# Как сделать обход в глубину графа в данной матрице?

Tags: python, матрицы, python-3.7, graph, dfs

Дана таблица из чисел размером N×N, каждое число в которой кодирует яркость пикселя.
Можно заменить яркость каждого пикселя на сумму яркостей в нем и в 8 соседних по стороне или углу пикселей. Для угловых пикселей и пикселей лежащих на границе считается только сумма яркостей пикселей.

Необходимо по таблице, в которой посчитана сумма яркостей, восстановить исходную таблицу.

В первой строке записано число N - размер матрицы. В следующих N строках задано по N целых чисел: яркости пикселей после применения операции.
Необходимо вывести N строк  по N чисел в каждой - яркости пикселей до применения операции. Если ответов несколько- вывести любой из них.

Пример:

Вход:

```
3
12 21 16
27 45 33
24 39 28
```

Выход:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На этом сайте подробное обьяснение этого алгоритма и его код

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dfs-traversal-of-a-tree-using-recursion/